# how to prove $\inf Z_A \notin Z_A$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $Z_A = \{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu (I_n) |\text{  $I_n$ are intervals and } A \subset \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n \}$. with $\mu(\cdot)$ is the lesbesque measure.

Give an example of a null set $A$ where $\inf Z_A \notin Z_A$ and prove this!

i was thinking about looking at $A = \{0\}$. Obviously the infinum is taking $I_n = \{0\}\text{ } \forall n$. so the $\inf Z_A = 0$. But the main confusion here for me is that in this case the $\inf Z_A \in Z_A$ because we can take $I_n = \{0\}\text{ } \forall n$.

So how do i construct such an A?????

Kees

Comment: Do you know any uncountable set of measure zero?

Comment: By the way, did you meant $A=\{0\}$ in the third paragraph?

Comment: not specifically to be honest. We can try using the cantor set maybe? I am new to the cantor set, but i vaguely remember it is an uncountable set with measure 0.

Comment: Presumably when you say that for $A=\{0\}$ we can take $I_n=0$ you meant $I_n=\emptyset$. But $A$ is not empty, so no you _can't_ let $I_n=\emptyset$ for all $n$.

Comment: no, i meant the row $I_n = \{0\} \forall n$. sorry for the typo's :$